# UITabbar nothing selected

Tags: ios, uitabbar

U have got an `UITabBar` (not an controller) when I select  an element, How can I change the `UITabBar` such that nothing is selected any more?

Answer (score 0):

```
myTabbar.selectedItem = nil; // will remove selection
```